# Edit richtext field and paste it edited in another richtext field

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, lotusscript

I'm heaving problems with a specific task on Lotus Notes. I have to copy a rich text field edit it and paste inside another rich text field. But when I edit the content the text style disappears. I've tried to use this solution:

http://www.bobzblog.com/tuxedoguy.nsf/dx/geek-o-terica-15-easy-conversion-of-notes-documents-to-mime-format-part-1

to copy the html and then edit the content. But I got another problem with this:

java.lang.ClassCastException: lotus.domino.local.Item incompatible with lotus.domino.RichTextItem

Can anyone help me with my task?
Thank you.

Comment: You need to show your code, not just a reference to a blog post with someone else's code. And you need to identify the exact line of code that is throwing the error so that people here know where to look for problems,

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify how you want to edit the richtext data. But if you by "edit" mean "programatically make changes to", you can do that in regular Lotusscript using the NotesRichTextItem class.

I wrote a mail-merge class a while back, and it is replacing content in a rich text field with other values, keeping the formatting. If you look at the code you can probably figure it out.

http://blog.texasswede.com/code-mail-mergeform-letters-in-lotuscript/

The relevant code is here:

```
Public Function MergedRichText() As NotesRichTextItem
    Dim range As NotesRichTextRange         
    Dim cnt As Integer
    Set tempbody = sourcefield
    Set range = tempbody.CreateRange 
    Forall p In placeholder
        Call p.ProcessPlaceHolder(sourcedoc, maindoc)
        If p.text = "" Then
            p.text = " -- "
        End If
        cnt =  range.FindAndReplace(p.placeholderstring, p.text, 1+4+8+16)            
    End Forall
    Call tempbody.Compact 
    Call tempbody.Update 
    Set targetfield = tempbody
    Set MergedRichText = tempbody
End Function
```